# Why have some threading problems been solved without extending java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, language-design, thread-synchronization

Some threading problems were solved without extending `java.lang.Object`.

The methods `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` are implemented on `Object`, which seems to me not to be the best decision since it pollutes the class's interface. It affects all classes in Java, which I think should have been avoided.

Next, the `synchronized` block takes an instance of type `Object`, allowing us to accidently pass shared instances (e.g. `String`), which can cause problems. They could have crafted a class `Mutex`/`Lock` in order to avoid this.

I wonder whether this comes with any technical advantages - e.g. performance - or  whether it is just bad design? Is there somewhere an *official* documentation, e.g. a [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0) or something similar - on why the Java language designers decided to work directly with `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: Why not ask the [OpenJDK devs](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo)?

Comment: Good idea. I think I'll drop a mail there if no answer will pop up here within some days.

Comment: @aboger What do you mean by "without extending `java.lang.Object`"? Every class extends from that class, it is not possible to **not** extend from that class.

Comment: @Program I mean, why does every class in Java implement e.g. `wait()`. Why isn't there a `class Mutex { public void wait(){} }`. Or why does `synchronized(a)` take an argument of type `Object`, not e.g. only instances of type `Mutex`.

Comment: I think that, in hindsight, the Java platform agrees this was unnecessary. Your `Mutex` class is called [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). It's an interesting question, but these "why are things this way" questions tend to invite speculation and opinion that isn't a good fit for stackoverflow. Software engineering might have place for them (I'm not as familiar with that site though).

Comment: I have a hard time to understand how asking for a reference to official documentation is opinion-based.

Comment: "**Questions asking us to** recommend or **find a** book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." [Emphasis added.]

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for future questions. Thanks for explaining and for the `Condition` reference.

Comment: at the time that this decision was made, java did not really follow a `JEP` process ([here is the first one](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/1)) There were people from Sun that decided what will the language look like. Very smart people, but they could not figure it out all. IMHO: this was a slight mistake, just like `Cloneable` and `clone` in `java.lang.Object`

Comment: It is easy to casually slap the "mistake" label on decisions of this sort -- far too easy.  The question of "should every object have a monitor" is one that is full of subtle tradeoffs.  The real value of asking such questions should not be to come to a "mistake or not" conclusion, but to understand what the _goals, priorities, and expectations_ were that would have led some of the best and brightest to make this particular choice in 1992.  (You could ask the same of hashCode() -- but the pragmatism of this choice is far more obvious.)

Comment: Jeez... Brian Goetz commenting my question O_o amazing. I recently asked my teacher Heinz Kabutz this question and he gave me an answer similar to your comment, pointing out the _subtle tradoffs_, the different state of knowledge back then and more. Trying to get an insight into these tradeoffs, _the goals, priorities, and expectations_ of 1992 was exactly the reason for this question. I was hoping for a reference to some documentation on this to dig deeper, as it sounds really interesting. Well, given your comment, I now understand pragmatism as one design decision, thank you.